# Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null

Tags: php, laravel

I want to sort query in relation by `type_order`:

```
public function posts()
{
    if (($this->type_order) == '1') {
        $type = 'id';
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'feed_posts')->orderBy($type);
    }
}
```

But get error:

```
FatalThrowableError
Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null
```

Comment: Where do you declare posts() method?

Answer (score 27):

I had this issue because i forgot to return

```
class Test extends Model 
{
    public function tests(){
       $this->hasMany(Test::class);
    }
}
```

Comment: duh! I totally just did this. lol

Comment: I take that back, i do this like once a month. lol

Answer (score 1):

This happens because Laravel often creates an empty instance of your model to construct queries/new instances. So when it creates a new instance to build a query, `posts()` actually returns `null` instead of a `BelongsToMany` relation.

To fix this you'll have to remove the conditional and solve that issue in another way.

Answer (score 0):

try use `setType()` kind of method to setting type then call like this  `$vaiable->setType()->posts;`

```
public $newType = 'id'; // default ordering is by id

public function setType()
{
    if (($this->type_order) == '1') {
        $this->newType = 'id';
    }
    return $this;
}    

public function posts()
{
    $result = $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'feed_posts');
    return $result->orderBy($this->newType);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function posts()
{
    if (($this->type_order) == '1') {
        $type = 'id';
        return $this->belongsToMany(Post::class, 'feed_posts')->orderBy($type);
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason is that not everytime inside your Laravel relation method you can access to `$this` object, for example on re-rendering [Livewire](https://laravel-livewire.com) component - in your relation method `$this` object **will be empty**. In your case `$this->type_order` **can be null** and you don't have else statement, thats why `Call to a member function addEagerConstraints() on null`